# Why is tabbing through fields failing weirdly in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm seeing strange behavior with Firefox's handling of tabbing through fields and I can't fathom why.  I've reduced the code on my page to a very simple reproduction of the issue.

Tabbing works totally fine until clicking above the `input` and to the right of the `label` in the page that is rendered from the following code:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label>Click on the right side of this line and tabbing stops working |</label>
<input>
```

Clicking below or at the level of the input causes tabbing to behave as expected once again.  Is this expected behavior and I'm just not understanding something about tabbing, or is it some sort of bug in the Firefox browser?

The Firefox version is 80.0.1 (64-bit) and I am on a desktop computer.

There are no issues in Chrome.

Comment: `tabindex` is an attribute you put on an element to control the order of *tabbing* through a document.

Comment: I'm aware.  Is the thrust of that statement that I should use "tabbing" throughout the wording of my question rather than "tabindexing"?  It seemed like I might cause less confusion by wording it that way since "tab" has multiple meanings in the context of a browser.

Comment: Yeah, "tabindex" is not a verb :). Interestingly, if you click to the right of the `input` tabbing works fine, it's only when you click to the right of the `label`....

Comment: Seemed extremely weird to me, I reported a Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1669016

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `width: 100%` to the `label`, then it works, since it spans the whole line.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<label>Click on the right side of this line and tabbing works |</label>
<input>
```

Comment: The example I included here isn't really what I have in code.  The real code has an element being displayed in a flex container such that it is in the center of the page and the threshold for triggering this weird failure is essentially the entire top half of the page.  I'd rather not have a label that spans that entire empty space, if possible.

Comment: This is a workaround to a specific piece of sample code, not an answer to the question, which is **Why?**.

Comment: Well, the answer to "why" is that the label otherwise doesn't extend to the area right of it, so clicking there won't select or focus it. And I added a solution for the sample code, which is expected to reproduce the problem AFAIK...

Comment: @Johannes Other browsers seem to handle this just fine, though.  I wouldn't think I'd have to select or click a specific element on the page in order to preserve expected tabbing behavior.  Like if the browser is the active window on my machine, I expect tabbing to, at the very least, cycle through the browser controls (ie: "back", "refresh", "url", etc).  It doesn't even do that in Firefox with the code I have above.